# ¿Cómo suporponer gráficos en R? (Gráfico de puntos y mapa)

Tags: base-de-datos, r, ggplot2

Hice un gráfico de puntos utilizando datos de longitud y latitud con el siguiente código:

```
##Archivo csv
gto<- read_csv(sprintf("http://fs.planeacion.sep.gob.mx/cct/cct11.csv"))

##Vector de niveles educativos (para ordenar)
nivel_ed <- c("Primaria", "Secundaria", "Bachillerato", "Superior")

gtomap <- subset(gto, select=c(longitud, latitud, nnivel)) %>%
    filter(nnivel%in%c("PRIMARIA", "SECUNDARIA", "BACHILLERATO", 
    "PEDAGOGICA, UNIVERSITARIA O TECNOLOGICA", "PROFESIONAL")) %>%
    mutate(nnivel= case_when(nnivel== "PEDAGOGICA, UNIVERSITARIA O TECNOLOGICA" ~ "Superior",
        nnivel=="PROFESIONAL" ~ "Superior", 
        nnivel=="SECUNDARIA" ~ "Secundaria",
        nnivel=="PRIMARIA" ~ "Primaria",
        nnivel=="BACHILLERATO" ~ "Bachillerato")) %>% 
    mutate(nnivel= factor(nnivel, levels=nivel_ed)) %>%
    melt(id =c("longitud","latitud"))  %>% 
    mutate(value= factor(value, levels=nivel_ed)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = longitud, y = latitud, col= value)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    labs(x = "", y="")

gtomap
```

Posteriormente, descargué un mapa utilizando:

```
##Para importar geom_sf
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

##Mapa
mapgto <- sf::read_sf("http://geoinfo.iplaneg.net/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=geonode%3Amgm_gto2010&mode=download", quiet=T)
map <- data.frame(mapgto) 

##El mapa se grafica directamente con

ggplot() + 
geom_sf(data=map)
```

Como podrán observar, los puntos y el mapa corresponden a las mismas coordenadas. Por tanto, quiero superponer el primer gráfico al segundo a fin de que el gráfico final contenga el mapa y los puntos que contienen la ubicación de mis variables de interés.
Sin embargo, si intento algo como:

```
gtomap + geom_sf(data=map)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objeto 'longitud' no encontrado
```

Se aprecia un error. He leído diversos tutoriales, pero no he encontrado alguno que me ofrezca una alternativa para mi problema específico. Agradezco cualquier orientación y comentario.

Comment: Alejandro, fijate en el objeto `map` que sale después de `data.frame(mapgto)`. Es un data.frame anidado, tiene listas dentro con las coordenadas. Seguramente `geom_sf` tiene un método interno para desanidarlas y hacer el mapa. (No lo probé para no instalar una versión en desarrollo de ggplot). Pero al no asignar con `aes()` las variables/columnas no coinciden con las de `gtomap`, por eso ese error. Sugerencia: para tu cartografía trata de usar un data.frame "puro" con columnas `latitud` y `longitud` a las que asignes a `y` y `x`. En ese caso te va a coincidir sin problemas con el otro df.

Comment: Hice esta guía hace un tiempo, más que nada para documentación propia, pero en una de esas te sirve para ver otras aproximaciones al problema: https://martinpaladino.github.io/Mapas_con_R.html En mi experiencia las funciones que "simplifican" hacer mapas al final lo complican, porque que quitan flexibilidad. Ya saldrá `tidymaps` para hacernos la vida más fácil. Si tengo tiempo en la tarde busco una respuesta propiamente dicha a tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, @mpaladino. Revisaré con detenimiento tu texto :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de investigar un poco más y leer con detenimiento esto:

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html

Entendí que lo que faltaba era incorporar directamente geom_sf a la llamada a ggplot y no hacerlo por fuera. Así, el código quedaría:

```
gtomap <- subset(gto, select=c(longitud, latitud, nnivel)) %>%
    filter(nnivel%in%c("PRIMARIA", "SECUNDARIA", "BACHILLERATO", 
    "PEDAGOGICA, UNIVERSITARIA O TECNOLOGICA", "PROFESIONAL")) %>%
    mutate(nnivel= case_when(nnivel== "PEDAGOGICA, UNIVERSITARIA O TECNOLOGICA" ~ "Superior",
        nnivel=="PROFESIONAL" ~ "Superior", 
        nnivel=="SECUNDARIA" ~ "Secundaria",
        nnivel=="PRIMARIA" ~ "Primaria",
        nnivel=="BACHILLERATO" ~ "Bachillerato")) %>% 
    mutate(nnivel= factor(nnivel, levels=nivel_ed)) %>%
    melt(id =c("longitud","latitud"))  %>% 
    mutate(value= factor(value, levels=nivel_ed)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = longitud, y = latitud, col= value, shape=value)) +
    geom_sf(data=map, inherit.aes=F) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~value) +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    labs(x = "", y="") 
gtomap
```

Si corren el código podrán ver el resultado